# Files missing in directory A but present in directory B

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to create:

- a list containing files present in a but missing in b
- a list containing files present in b but missing in a

This is my code so far:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

A_DIR_1=/tmp/1
A_DIR_2=/tmp/2
A_DIR_3=/tmp/3    
B_DIR_1=/tmp/1
B_DIR_2=/tmp/2
B_DIR_3=/tmp/3

for i in {1..3}
do
   A="A_DIR_$i"
   B="B_DIR_$i"
   if [ d ${!A} ]; then
      bash -c 'diff -u <(find "${!B}" |sed "s:${!B}::") <(find "${!A}" |sed "s:${!A}::") |sed "/^+\//!d; s::${!A}/:"' >> /tmp/fileA
      bash -c 'diff -u <(find "${!A}" |sed "s:${!A}::") <(find "${!B}" |sed "s:${!A}::") |sed "/^+\//!d; s::${!B}/:"' >> /tmp/fileB
   fi
 done
```

However, when I run it, I get the following error: `find: cannot search : No such file or directory'`. Why is this? The directories definitely exist.

Comment: Why the recursive `bash` invocations? It's a quoting nightmare and should not be necessary, if you change the shebang to use `/bin/bash` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mm, imho your code is difficult.

If I've understood you clearly, that can help:

Prepare:

```
mkdir /tmp/dir1
mkdir /tmp/dir2
touch /tmp/dir1/test{1..12}
touch /tmp/dir2/test{1..15}
touch /tmp/dir1/test{22..25}
```

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir1=/tmp/dir1
dir2=/tmp/dir2


diff_result=$(diff -u "${dir1}" "${dir2}")
echo "${diff_result}" | grep "${dir1}" | awk '{print $NF}' > /tmp/files_only_in_dir1
echo "${diff_result}" | grep "${dir2}" | awk '{print $NF}' > /tmp/files_only_in_dir2
```

Output:

```
$ cat /tmp/files_only_in_dir1 
test22
test23
test24
test25
$ cat /tmp/files_only_in_dir2
test13
test14
test15
```